# CircleCI 2.0 - SSH keys are missing (migrating from Circle 1.0)

Tags: capistrano, continuous-deployment, ssh-keys, circleci, circleci-2.0

Migrating from Circle 1.0 to 2.0.
I can fetch my code without any problem, but the ssh key used to deploy seems to be unavailable.

The key is in the project ssh permissions
[image: project ssh keys permissions]

There are no `~/.ssh/config` file, and the key is not there either:
[image]

So when the deploy step kicks in, it fails:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "develop" ]; then
  bundle exec cap staging deploy
else
  echo "Not on develop branch"
fi

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as [redacted]@staging.captaincontrat.com: Authentication failed for user [redacted]@staging.captaincontrat.com

Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user [redacted]@staging.captaincontrat.com

Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Exited with code 1
```

I tried using the `add_ssh_keys` step but the key remains unavailable.
[As the documentation specifies that it adds all keys by default](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#addsshkeys) anyway, I removed it.

Here's the config.yml file, most of which is the result of the migration script:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/captaincontrat/captaincontrat
    parallelism: 1
    shell: /bin/bash --login
    environment:
      CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
      CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    # As our ruby version is a bit old, we can't use a pre-configured circle image.
    # So we need to use one with a large number of languages and other packages.
    # Once ruby is updated, choose a more recent image for better and faster builds.
    # https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
    docker:
    - image: circleci/build-image:ubuntu-14.04-XXL-upstart-1189-5614f37
      command: /sbin/init
    steps:
    - checkout
    # Prepare for artifact and test results
    - run: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
    # Dependencies
    - run:
        name: Show me the available ssh keys
        command: 'ls -lha ~/.ssh'
    - run:
        name: Start redis
        command: 'sudo redis-cli ping >/dev/null 2>&1 || sudo service redis-server
          start; '
    # Restore the dependency cache
    - restore_cache:
        keys:
        # This branch if available
        - captaincontrat-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        # Default branch if not
        - captaincontrat-develop-
    - run: gem install bundler
    - run: echo -e "export RAILS_ENV=test\nexport RACK_ENV=test" >> $BASH_ENV
    - run: 'bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle
        --jobs=4 --retry=3 '
    - save_cache:
        key: captaincontrat-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        paths:
        - vendor/bundle
        - ~/.bundle
    - run: |-
        mkdir -p config && echo 'test:
          adapter: mysql2
          database: circle_ruby_test
          username: ubuntu
          host: localhost
        ' > config/database.yml
    - run:
        command: bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load --trace
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          RACK_ENV: test
    # Test
    #   This would typically be a build job when using workflows, possibly combined with build
    - run: bin/rspec_all
    - run: bundle exec codeclimate-test-reporter $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/coverage/.resultset.json
    # Deploy if develop
    #   This should be in a workflow, but workflows can't cancel redundant jobs for now.
    - deploy:
        name: Deploy to staging if branch is develop
        command: |
           if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "develop" ]; then
             bundle exec cap -t staging deploy
           else
             echo "Not on develop branch => Not deploying to staging"
           fi
    # Teardown
    #   If you break your build into multiple jobs with workflows, you will probably want to do the parts of this that are relevant in each
    # Save test results
    - store_test_results:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    # Save artifacts
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
```

What am I missing‽
Thanks!

## EDIT: here's the solution

The key points are:
- `add_ssh_keys`
- then `run eval`ssh-agent`&& ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa*` before `cap deploy`, as I need `.ssh/id_rsa` to checkout the code on the repo via agent forwarding

```
# Deploy if develop
- add_ssh_keys
- deploy:
    name: Deploy to staging if branch is develop
    command: |
       if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "develop" ]; then
         eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa* && bundle exec cap staging deploy
  # ... snip
```

To ensure agent forwarding, you can add `set :ssh_options, forward_agent: true` to the capistrano stage configuration.

Comment: just a note:  you can provide an answer to your own question, you don't have to use the question itself to provide the answer.  that will all us to upvote and comment on the answer.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the `add_ssh_keys` step in order to have your SSH keys injected into the container. This step needs to be before the `deploy` step.

When the documentation says all keys are added by default, it means when using `add_ssh_keys`. It says that because you can also use that special step to add a specific keys.

Comment: Thanks! That was the first step. I then had some trouble forwarding the ssh-agent with the correct keys but I got it fixed.

Comment: Cool. If possible, adding what you did here as a comment might help future people finding this question on SO.

Comment: The key points are:
- `add_ssh_keys`
- then run `eval \`ssh-agent\` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa*` before `cap deploy`, as I need `.ssh/id_rsa` to checkout the code on the repo via agent forwarding

`
# Deploy if develop
- add_ssh_keys
- deploy:
    name: Deploy to staging if branch is develop
    command: |
       if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "develop" ]; then
         eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa* && bundle exec cap staging deploy
      # ... snip
`
To ensure agent forwarding, you can add `set :ssh_options, forward_agent: true` to the capistrano stage configuration.

Comment: Added solution to the question as the formatting of comments is not great for the level of details I want to provide :)

Comment: if you are required to add `add_ssh_keys` somewhere, the documentation is definitely wrong: http://web.archive.org/web/20180629174551/https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key/  (point in time snapshot thanks to archive.org).   that very clearly states that you only have to add the key via the UI....   the docu for `add_ssh_keys` agrees.  http://web.archive.org/web/20180215030227/https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#add_ssh_keys

Comment: opened an issue with circle to hopefully correct this docu - https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/issues/2462

Comment: circle has updated their docu to reflect the requirement for `add_ssh_keys`